# How to use Session in Models in MVC .NET Core 2.2

Tags: session, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use Session in a MVC .NET Core 2.2 project but not only in the Controller but also in the Model.

There are examples to show the usage in Controllers but I did not find any information on how to access the Session in Model classes. Also I need to say that Models are not in the Web project but in a seperate Class Library project.

Is there a proper answer or solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally inadvisable to use the session in a class library.You'd better pass the particular values to your library call or just pass the whole `IHttpContextAccessor` to get `HttpContext` in model class.

So instead of accessing the settings in the library method, you do:

1.Class Library.

1) Install below packages for your Class Library:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions" Version="2.2.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

2) Model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Product
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

        public Product(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        {   
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;       
            Name = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("your session key");
        }

        public string Name { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

2.Web App.

1) Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

2) Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
         var product = new ClassLibrary1.Product(_httpContextAccessor );
    }
}
```